# win_ping return value and storing in a variable

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook which uses win_ping module.

```
---
  - name: Ping Test
    win_ping:
      register: var_ping_output
      debug: var = var_ping_output
```

How can i get the return values from win_ping, a successful ping or a failed ping together with the servername, and to be stored in a variable. When I execute the above, I get the following errors.

```
unsupported parameters f or (win_ping) modue, register, debug. supported parameters include: data
```

The playbook is being executed via ansible tower.

Comment: Traditionally it's via `register: win_ping_output` followed by `debug: var=win_ping_output` and see if it contains what you're expecting (you may also have to say `ignore_errors: yes` in order to have a failed ping not bomb your play)

Comment: Did this, please see the errors above. I edited the question. thanks

Comment: Did you try by adding "data" parameter as per the documentation?

Comment: The [`register:` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task) should be at the same level as `name:`. The "followed by" part is [`- debug: var=win_ping_output`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html), sorry for the lack of specificity